# Is there a benefit from having a subclass method that only calls the overridden superclass method?

Tags: java, inheritance

While refactoring I came across the following method in a subclass:

```
public void disposeResultsTable() {
    super.disposeResultsTable();
}
```

What are the benefits to keeping this method rather than simply allowing the inherited superclass method to be called?

Comment: Only reason I can think of is if the superclass function is ```protected```. This would make it public.

Comment: Or package-visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only *technical* reason I can think of is what [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10001688/michael-bianconi) proposed in the comments - making a restricted method become `public`.

However, I can think of a few *human* reasons.

For instance, this could be a convenient place to place a breakpoint for debugging invocations of `disposeResultsTable` of the child class. Or perhaps this was meant as a placeholder - "*remember to implement this method for this class*", or maybe someone wanted to explicitly point out to the reader of this code that this class uses the parent's implementation of `disposeResultsTable`. There are probably a bunch more options.

Have you tried looking up the history of this piece of code in the VCS? Maybe there's a helpful commit message from the original author.

Comment: In my case, I think it must be one of these human reason or it may be boilerplate, as other sibling subclasses all have more interesting implementations of this method. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Malt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502600/3182664) shows a common reason for overriding a method trivially by only calling the super implementation, namely to change the visibility from `protected` to `public`. Whether or not this might be the case in your example depends on the visibility of the respective method in the superclass...

However, there is another possible reason - although it might be a bit far-fetched and unusual - and this possible reason is *reflection*: The [`Class#getDeclaredMethods`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) method only returns the methods that are... well, *declared* in this class.

For example, consider the following program:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TrivialOverride
{
    static class BaseClass
    {
        void method0() {}
        void method1() {}
    }
    static class ChildClass extends BaseClass
    {
        void method0() {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        printDeclaredMethods(BaseClass.class);
        printDeclaredMethods(ChildClass.class);
    }

    private static void printDeclaredMethods(Class<?> c)
    {
        System.out.println("Declared methods in " + c.getSimpleName());
        for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods())
        {
            System.out.println(m.getName());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Declared methods in BaseClass
method0
method1

Declared methods in ChildClass
method0
```

So `method0` only appears in the list of declared methods of the child class because it was overridden from the base class.

Comment: Nice! Hadn’t thought of reflection.